# how to get os version via browser.php

Tags: php

i using [browser.php](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) for detect OS name that users use it.
but my question is that how we can get OS version of users use. this script did not provide any method or property for that . 
for example i want to show windows version that users use it include seven,XP and so on.

what is solution? please Help me if can

Comment: Why don't you ask that script author?

Comment: You are also aware that any user can send a fake browser agent to the server, so browser detection in general is not reliable?

Comment: i need to a quick answer. ask script author can Take a long time

Comment: Yes I know steve. but i don not use it for important thing. i just get the user agent string and save it to DB and then show complete details when he/she login to site. just it.

Comment: Simple answer is, with current version, you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Browsercap class](https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap) instead, since it appears (from the comments above) that the tool you're currently using doesn't support this feature. The Browsercap class is an off-shoot of PHP's native `get_browser()` method, though the class doesn't require the types of ini-configurations that the native function does. The class is also a fully standalone solution.

Setup is easy:

```
// Loads the class
require 'path/to/Browscap.php';

// The Browscap class is in the phpbrowscap namespace, so import it
use phpbrowscap\Browscap;

// Create a new Browscap object (loads or creates the cache)
$bc = new Browscap('path/to/the/cache/dir');

// Get information about the current browser's user agent
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();

// Output the result
print_r($current_browser);
```

The output will be your resulting object, full of relevant data (including the Platform/OS):

```
stdClass Object
(
    /* ... */
    [Parent] => Safari 3.1
    [Platform] => MacOSX
    [Browser] => Safari
    [Version] => 3.1
    /* ... */
)
```